# pgfplots with LuaLaTeX - totally different results

Tags: pgfplots, luatex

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,colormap/blackwhite}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[view={-60}{40}, hide axis=true, ticks=none, line join=round, line cap=round, clip=false]
    \addplot3[surf, samples=51, domain=-2:2, y domain=-2:2, line width=0.2pt, fill=white, point meta=0] {x^2*y/(x^4+y^2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I run this with LaTeX I get this (which is not perfect but pretty much what I want):

[image: pgfplots with LaTeX]

But I just read that pgfplots was supposed to be faster and more accurate with LuaLaTeX, so I gave it a try.  This is the result:

[image: pgfplots with LuaLaTeX]

Huh?  Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: I don't know what is difference but when I use `compat=1.8` instead of `compat=1.16`, same result is obtained with LaTeX.

Comment: I think you need at least 1.12 to see a difference, see pgfplots manual.

Comment: I executed it with `compat=1.8` and got it correctly as well.

Comment: When using `compat=1.16` and LuaTeX, `pgfplots` will delegate the function evalutation to the Lua backend, which works at considerably higher precision than TeX.  That is when you hit the singularities.  One option would be to use `samples=50, domain=-2:2`.  Because of the even number of samples, zero will be excluded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're seeing differences in handling the unbounded (NaN) values that result from division by zero in your equation at (0, 0). Either avoid the division by zero by using for example

```
{x^2*y/(x^4+y^2+1e-6)}
```

or set pgfplots option `unbounded coords=jump` (which replaces the default of `unbounded coords=discard` that leads to the artefact).

Comment: +1. I wonder if you could also mention the possibility to plot `ifthenelse(x==0 && y==0,0,x^2*y/(x^4+y^2))`, which does not deform the plot (I know that the deformation is negligible), or to set the samples to some even number, in which (for symmetric domains) the singularity gets avoided as well.